# Why do i get this error (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nomethoderror, cloud9

I am having a problem with my ruby on rails cloud 9 code while my task is to create an article from the UI and save it to the database when I hit submit.

This is my image of my problem:

[image]

This is my cloud 9 code

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  # root 'welcome#index'
  resources :articles

  root 'pages#home'
  get 'about', to: 'pages#about'
end
```

Articles controller (articles_controller.rb):

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @article = Article.new 
  end
end
```

new.html.erb in articles folder in views:

```
<h1>Create an article</h1>

<%= form_for @article do |f| %>

    <p>
        <%= f.label :title %>
        <%= f.text_area :title %>
    </p>

<% end %>
```

Article model (article.rb) :

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

I have done a migration and this is my migrate file :

```
class CreateArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    @article = Article.new

    create_table :articles do |t|
      t.string :title
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: The data in your migration file is wrong. I suggest you to read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Comment: The indentation here is practically non-existent and that really impairs readability. Do make an effort to keep your code as clean and presentable as possible here when asking questions. It's not nice to make others struggle to understand what's going on.

Comment: I am so sorry I am new to stack overflow I do not intend for people to struggle, I have changed and tried my best to duplicate it from my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your migration seems to be missing the `title` column

```
class CreateArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :articles do |t|
      t.string :title
    end
  end
end
```

Also your model should inherit from `ApplicationRecord`

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
end
```

Or `ActiveRecord::Base` if your Rails version is less than 5

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Comment: I have tried that but it is giving me this                                                                         NoMethodError undefined method `title' for #<Article id: nil>

Comment: now i am getting this : uninitialized constant ApplicationRecord

Comment: You must be using an older Rails version. Inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base` instead.

Comment: I am using rails version : Rails 4.2.5 (if this helps you)

Comment: I have tried the ActiveRecord : : Base and now it is giving me the error : undefined method `title' for #<Article id: nil>

Comment: did you rollback your previous migration and run the updated one?

Comment: I tried that and I am getting this error with :rake db:migrate
== 20170820190312 CreateArticles: migrating ===================================
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

Could not find table 'articles'

Comment: @ShashiYerra do you still have this line `@article = Article.new` in the migration? If so remove it as it will try to ensure the table exists for reflection and type casting and it does not exist yet. Also it doesn't do anything and does not belong in a migration file. the migration posted in this answer is correctly what your migration file should look like

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the line `@article = Article.new` from migration file.

This would create a instance of Article using `new` keyword while you'll run the migration and it will be a nil instance, that's why you got the above error

> Article id: nill

Because the last record was nil and you're looking for title of that record which primary key also nil.